# How to target a search result page?

Tags: conditional-tags

I'am wondering how to target a search result page within the functions.php file in wordpress.

I know about "is_search" for the search page but what about the search result page ?

Can we put a condition with the query or something?

Thanks in advance.

All the best

Comment: Hi, what exactly are you trying to achieve? It will be easier to solve this using some examples, I guess...

Comment: There is no standard "search page". `is_search()` _is_ for the search results page.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by search result page, the page that shows the results of a search query will return `true` for `is_search`, there are no other pages

Comment: Hello guys,
Thanks for answering.
I mean by result page, the page whose URL contains ?s= 
The page displaying the results after the user query on the search.php page.
Thanks

Comment: @TomJNowell yes indeed is_search is the search result page.. 
thank you

Comment: `is_search` indicates that the main query is a search query, and when the main query is a search query, the `search.php` template is loaded so that the results are shown. URLs with `?s=` are search queries, any distinction between search page and search results page is nonexistent, they are the same thing. There is no page named "Search" or a page that is for making a search but not showing results.

Comment: You never mentioned, why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve that requires this? And why didn't you ask about that instead?

Comment: Hello @TomJNowell, thanks for your explanation. You are right, I will clarify the context. I was actually trying to have an impact on the layout of the page that is rendered after the use of a searchform.

Comment: I am working on a WP website with woocommerce. I have two search forms. When I used the WP searchform `search.php` is called as well as the `loop.php` and `content.php`. So the conditional `if is_search()`  seemed possible to me. 

The thing is with the wc search form, `archive.-product.php` was called. No presence of `search.php`. 

Anyways, the conditional works for both in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'am wondering how to target a search result page within the functions.php file in wordpress.

Use `is_search`, and the `search.php` template

> I know about "is_search" for the search page but what about the search result page ?

They are the same thing, `is_search` indicates the main query is a search query. When `is_search` is true, WordPress loads `search.php` as the template, falling back to `archive.php` then `index.php` if they aren't present.

I'm not sure where the idea of a separate search page, and a separate search results page came from, but that's not how it works. There are search results, and a search form that can appear in any place, but no search page.

> Can we put a condition with the query or something?

If you want to modify the main query, use the `pre_get_posts` filter. This is true for all queries, not just search queries, and allows you to intercept the query parameters before WordPress fetches the posts to change what's fetched.

Comment: I didn't want to modify the main query. I was trying to imagine a condition that would work if the search query was called..